# Using EJS how do I insert a value if it exists

Tags: ejs

Why doesn't this work:

```
 <input type="text" name="givenName" <% if(givenName) {%> value="<%= givenName %>" <% } %>/><br/>
```

It throws a reference error saying givenName is not defined, which it may not be and is the reason for the conditional.

Comment: The answer to this question worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230470/how-to-use-if-statements-in-underscore-js-templates/9321127#9321127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rob you want to check `if (locals.givenName)`

```
 <input type="text" name="givenName" <% if(locals.givenName) {%> value="<%= givenName %>" <% } %>/><br/>
```

Comment: Webstorm gives error when using ejs code inside tags