# How to write a conditional if statement using underscore template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a `Name` and `Status` fields on my table and I want to display the values, Active and Inactive for the Status field. Here is the template I'm using:

```
  <tbody>
<% _.each(accountLists, function(account) { if (account.active == 'true') ? 'Active': 'Inactive'%>
        <tr>
            <td><%= account.active %></td>
        </tr>
    <% }) %>
</tbody>
```

When I run, the template throws:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Why?

For reference, below is my accountView.js

```
var AccountList = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){

},

    el:'#sub-account-list', 
    render: function(id){

    var self = this;
        var accountList = new SubAccountCollection([],{ id: id });

        accountList.fetch({
        success: function(accountLists){

            var data = accountLists.toJSON();
            var accounts = data[0].data.items;
            var template = $("#sub-account-list").html(_.template(tmpl, {accounts:accounts}));

                },
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: i understand i should have added this question to my existing question before, but anyways, i resolved my issue i was facing. Thanks for the help..however i am stuck at this another issue, im trying to resolve on how can i write conditional statements in underscore template. Above is the code i have edited to show what im trying to achieve..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use if statements in underscore.js templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230470/how-to-use-if-statements-in-underscore-js-templates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't have much to do with underscore templates - it will translate roughly into:

```
_.each(accountLists, function(account) {
    if (account.active == 'true') ? 'Active': 'Inactive'
    echo ("<tr><td>" + account.active "</td></tr>");
})
```

I'm not sure what you wanted to do here, but this is horribly mixing the [*if statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) with the [*conditional operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) syntax. Use either

```
<tbody>
    <% _.each(accountLists, function(account) {
        if (account.active == 'true') { %>
        <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
    <%  } else { %>
        <tr>
            <td>Inactive</td>
        </tr>
    <%  }
    }); %>
</tbody>
```

or

```
<tbody>
    <% _.each(accountLists, function(account) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= (account.active == 'true') ? 'Active': 'Inactive' %></td>
        </tr>
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Didn't realize you could put JS expressions in `<%=` statements, I like `_.templates` 100x more now!