# how to check a model property using if conditions in backbone template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to use a backbone template to render a table with a model object. while rendering the table i have to create a table column depending upon the model property. i tried doing

```
<script id="table-rows" type="text/template">
<td> <span class="status"> {{ status }} </span> </td>
<% if (status == 'completed') { %>
<td>
something
</td>
<% } %>
</script>
```

my view for single row am calling the render method like

```
render: function () {
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
return this;
}
```

but this is rendering the column always even the condition is not matching.
Let me know where am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230470/how-to-use-if-statements-in-underscore-js-templates).

Comment: What do your `_.templateSettings` look like?

Comment: _.templateSettings.interpolate = /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g;

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this:

```
<% if ('{{status}}' == 'completed') { %>
<td>
something
</td>
<%}%>
```

Comment: no luck, the condition passing always and printing the tablecell

Comment: Can you output the value of status in the td so we can make sure it's not "completed"?

Comment: {{ status }} value is printing correctly like running and completed for the rows. but the if conditional is not working

Comment: <% if (false) { %> also not evaluating its simply omiting this block and printing tabe cell.

Comment: Can you submit more of the code? There must be something else going on.

Comment: Did you modify your _.templateSettings? Did you change interpolate? what about evaluate?