# Using lodash templates, how can I check if a variable exists?

Tags: javascript, lodash, template-engine

I'm using Lodash templates.

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="example-template">
  <% if (typeof(leadingIconClass) !== "undefined") { %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<%= leadingIconClass %>" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <% } %>

  <% if (typeof(headline) !== "undefined") { %>
    <strong><%= headline %></strong>
  <% } %>

  <%= message %>

  <% if (typeof(mainHTML) !== "undefined") { %>
    <div class="group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <%= mainHTML %>
    </div>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

**Data to provide to template:**

```
var data = {
  message: 'Are you sure?'
};
```

**Compile template and append to container:**
                  `$container.prepend(_.template($("#example-template").html())(data));`

The approach I have written above (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230755/83916) works well, but I really don't like the `if` statements as in `<% if (typeof(headline) !== "undefined") { %>`. But when I simply write `<% if (headline) { %>`, it will say that headline is undefined.

Is there a more simple way to check if a variable exists using lodash templates that will not clutter up the html?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to access an undefined variable in JavaScript will result in an exception *unless* you use `typeof`. There is no real way around that.

However, if you wrap your whole template in another object, then using an `if` the way you want should work (as a property missing on an object results in `undefined`, not an exception):

```
var data = {
  data: {
    message: 'Are you sure?'
  }
};
```

And then in your template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="example-template">
  <% if (data.leadingIconClass) { %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-<%= data.leadingIconClass %>" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <% } %>

...
```

Comment: Another possibility `<span class="glyphicon <%= data.leadingIconClass ? 'glyphicon-' + data.leadingIconClass : '' %>" aria-hidden="true"></span>` This allows you to skip the `if` condition

Comment: That would not have the same effect, since the original idea was not to display the `<span>` at all when that variable is not present.